# Word meaning "to choose or take something as one's own"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I was having a conversation with an agent of an Internet service provider and the reason I called them was because I'm confused about a plan they have that is very similar to the one I currently have and I wanted to find out the difference. The conversation was coming nearer to the end and the agent asked me if there was anything else she could assist me with, and I said something along the lines of

> No that's all, I actually have the Flex plan with you guys(the plan that's very similar to the one I had confusion about), I was just confused about the 30-day pass, but now I understand. *I'll think about it if I want to consider the 30-day Flex plan(the one I had confusion about), thanks very much*.

The last sentence of my reply, is there a word/phrasal verb that could replace *consider* to mean *to choose or take something as one's own*?

I figured there could be a much better expression to use than *consider*. I don't want to say *choose* or *use* because they seem too strong because the whole intention of my call is to clear the confusion I have with this other plan that's very similar to the plan I currently have and not to decide on getting a plan and I'm pretty satisfied with my current plan though perhaps I might consider about this other plan, it's not my first intention.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For *choose or take as one’s own*, Collins Dictionary has [***adopt***](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/adopt):

> **adopt** *verb*
>
> 1. (law) to bring (a person) into a specific relationship, esp to take (another’s child) as one’s own child
> 2. to choose and follow (a plan, technique, etc)
> 3. to take over (an idea, etc) as if it were one’s own
> 4. to take on; assume ⇒ to adopt a title
> 5. to accept (a report, etc)

However, you might also ***take up*** the Flex plan, or ***take advantage of it***. Certainly your sentence “I’ll think about it if I want to consider the 30-day Flex plan” might have been “I’ll consider whether I want to take up the 30-day Flex plan” (or *adopt* or *take advantage of*).

Comment: @ErikE: There's no point in that sort of change. It wasn't wrong to start with. As it's still not wrong, there's no point in rolling back the edit. But please don't change what is not wrong.

Comment: I had never heard of "Collins". Given that [the rules](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) require inclusion of the author's name in plain text, your citation, to me, was incomplete (like if you had just used a last name, not first and last). If syndicated in a medium where links are lost, the full name becomes important.

Comment: Erik, I'm aware of the importance of text and disappearing links; [I wrote that meta answer](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/5196/18696). Collins is the publisher; that name suffices (like "Oxford" or "Merriam-Webster") in order to attribute the source. The same applies to just using a surname -- that's fine too. As it happens, this answer (and [Jim's](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/113744/18696)) were written before the policy was introduced. Mine complied with it even then.

Comment: I understand what you're saying. Thanks for clarifying. I just have to use my best judgment, as I did and will!

Answer (score 2):

In a more conversational tone, like on the telephone here, you can just use ***go for***:

> I'll have to think about whether I want to **go for** the 30-Day Flex Plan.

[***go for***](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/go-for#go-for_8) : 3. **go for something** [informal] to choose a particular thing

Answer (score -3):

Appropriate. ap·pro·pri·ate
adjective
əˈprōprē-it/

**1.
take (something) for one's own use, typically without the owner's permission.
"his images have been appropriated by advertisers"
synonyms:   seize, commandeer, expropriate, annex, arrogate, sequestrate, sequester, take over, hijack More
steal, take;
informalswipe, nab, bag, pinch
plagiarize, copy;
poach, steal, borrow;**
informalrip off

2.
devote (money or assets) to a special purpose.
"there can be problems in appropriating funds for legal expenses"
synonyms:   allocate, assign, allot, earmark, set aside, devote, apportion More
Origin

late Middle English: from late Latin appropriatus, past participle of appropriare ‘make one's own,’ from ad- ‘to’ + proprius ‘own, proper.’
Translate appropriate to
Use over time for: appropriate.

From Google.

Comment: I'm not the downvoter; however, note that Google is not the source of the definition, Google is providing the definition given in the [Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/appropriate).

Comment: Please note that the definition you mean is not an *adjective*, nor is it pronounced the way you've notated. The *verb* meaning for *appropriate* is pronounced differently in the final syllable. When you have corrected this and the incorrect attribution as the other commenter stated, reply here and I'll remove my downvote.